# Getting old account notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a notification problem with Firebase_messaging connected to Flutter.

I have the notification that works when I log in to my account.  The problem is if I switch accounts, I get the notifications from the old account.

I would like Firebase_messaging Flutter to disconnect the token from the phone if I disconnect the account.

Do you have a solution?
How can I check the account token every time I go to the home_page?

Ps: I have also tried clearing my app's cache and storage but the problem persists

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the current token using [deleteToken()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html) whenever a user logs out. This will invalidate the token associated to the old user. Then, make sure to generate a [new](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onTokenRefresh.html) one after a new user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Yuji Bry.

So I did this personally:

- For disconnection :

> Future deleteToken() {
> return FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();
> }

- For connection :

> NotificationService.getToken().then((value) {
> DatabaseService(userCredential.user!.uid).saveToken(value);
> });

PS : For the connection I have to do like this for the moment because personally the "onTokenRefresh" does not work for me.
The token therefore changes with each connection (so if 2 phones are connected to the same account, only the last phone that knows connected to the account will have the notifications)